# React local storage for staying signed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, local-storage

I am trying to recreate a basic register to sign in cats.

While on the Daily Log page the cats stay signed in. However, when I move to the History component all the sign in status data is wiped. How can I use local storage so it will keep the cats signed in when I click on Daily Log again after going to 'History'.

I have a basic understanding of local storage but don't know how to implement useState's and useEffects to make it work.

```js
import "./CatSign.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import SignedIn from "./SignedIn.js";
import whiteCat from "./Pics/whiteCat.jpg";
import spotty from "./Pics/spotty.jpg";
import small from "./Pics/small.jpg";
import clouded from "./Pics/cloudedleopard.jpg";
import leopard from "./Pics/leopard.jpg";
import tiger from "./Pics/tiger.jpg";
import whiteTiger from "./Pics/whiteTiger.jpg";

export default function CatSign(props) {
  const [signIn, setSignIn] = useState(false);
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(true);
  const [cat, setCat] = useState(null);
  const [container, setContainer] = useState(null);

  const cats = ["Mittens", "Bao", "Amber", "Tash", "Kasia", "Luna", "Spike"];
  const photoArray = [
    whiteCat,
    spotty,
    small,
    clouded,
    leopard,
    tiger,
    whiteTiger,
  ];

  let hello = "Stored";
  let init = "Jug";

  let stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(hello));
  const [data, setData] = useState(stored || init);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data === null && setContainer) localStorage.removeItem(hello);
    else localStorage.setItem(hello, JSON.stringify(data));
  }, [data, hello]);

  function handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target.innerText === "Sign In") {
      e.target.innerText = "Sign Out";
      e.target.style.background = "#feffff";
      setContainer(e.target.parentNode.children[2]);
      setCat(e.target.parentNode.children[1].innerText);
      setIsShown((current) => !current);
      setSignIn(true);
    } else {
      e.target.innerText = "Sign In";
      e.target.parentNode.children[2].innerText = `Signed Out`;
      e.target.style.background = "#f0677a";
    }
  }

  if (props.dailyLog) {
    return (
      <div className="CatSign">
        <div
          className="catsExpected"
          style={{ display: isShown ? "block" : "none" }}
        >
          You have {cats.length} cats expected today
        </div>
        {cats.map((cat, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              className="childContainer"
              key={cat}
              style={{ display: isShown ? "flex" : "none" }}
            >
              <img className="catPic" src={photoArray[index]} alt="Cat"></img>
              <p className="cat"> {cat} </p>
              <p className="status">Signed Out</p>
              <button className={"signInOut"} onClick={handleClick}>
                Sign In
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <SignedIn
          signIn={signIn}
          setSignIn={setSignIn}
          cat={cat}
          setIsShown={setIsShown}
          container={container}
        />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Please refer to my code https://github.com/AlexPD93/tiney-challenge-react.

Answer (score -1):

There are already some implementations of `useState` that make use of localStorage to persist the state between sessions.

Here is one from josh comeau: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/react-hooks/use-sticky-state/

Also, here it is one that I've used in the past: https://gist.github.com/andreadev-it/f2d59e3e76e08208ea912b4fded3f2f5#file-uselocalstorage-js

This of course implies that you are using react states to check if the cats are signed in. Without more knowledge about your project, this is my best advice.

Comment: Thank you. I have uploaded my code of the page I believe to be relevant